# What is the way to access my website on Apache server computer throw internet from anther pc

Tags: apache, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008, ubuntu-server

I am new on computer networking. I install Apache server on my Ubuntu desktop computer. And i made a website on this PC. When i connect my PC With internet using a dial-up (Mobile Broadband) modem then i find my public IP or IPv4 address on my connection status. When i type this IP address on my PC browser it runs my web-app or website. But when i use the same IP address on my another computer that can't open my website. I also try IIS server with windows server and windows desktop. My public IP work only my PC but not other PC. Can anyone tell me what is the way to connect my PC or Server with internet and people can access my web-app from internet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [ping](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/ping.8.html)? If you cannot reach the server using that method, your connection problem has nothing to do with the web server. That's a start :-)